# GCP apt-get install and update stopped working properly

Tags: debian, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have 2 compute engine instances:

**One** is running for about half a year, today for the first time I get:

```
Err:11 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-stretch InRelease The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:
```

**Another** I just setup today from a clean Debian 9 image, and it doesn't let me apt-get install anything:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-fpm
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-fpm'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-fpm'
```

Didn't have that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Regarding the second issue** I believe you have to run:

```
$ apt-get update
```

> **apt-get** **update**:
>   Used to re-synchronize the package index files from their sources. The indexes of available packages are fetched from the location(s) specified in /etc/apt/sources.list. An update should always be performed before an upgrade or dist-upgrade.

Sometimes the packages you are interested into are not part of the standard `source.list` and you need to add the sources carefully doublechecking them.

For example for `php7.2-fpm` you need to [update them](https://ayesh.me/Ubuntu-PHP-7.2):

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg 
https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm
```

**Regarding the first issue**: it has been a [temporary problem](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/known-issues#keyexpired) for Google Compute engine, now everything should be back to normal behaviour, but if it is not the case you can force a manual update of the old key running:

```
$ curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about GCP problem. As for the apt-get update - I managed it as well, was my mistake - I installed Ubuntu rep on Debian by mistake.